# Skipping every other element after the first

Tags: python, list, slice, element

I have the general idea of how to do this in Java, but I am learning Python and I am not sure how to do it in Python.

I need to implement a function that returns a list containing every other element of the source list, starting with the first element.

Thus far, I have this and I am not sure how to do from here:

```
def altElement(a):
    b = []
    for i in a:
        b.append(a)
        
    print b
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
def altElement(a):
    return a[::2]
```

Answer (score 100):

Slice notation `a[start_index:end_index:step]`

```
return a[::2]
```

where `start_index` defaults to `0` and `end_index` defaults to the `len(a)`.

Answer (score 33):

Alternatively, you could do:

```
for i in range(0, len(a), 2):
    #do something
```

The extended slice notation *is* much more concise, though.

Comment: This was helpful for me, but it's different from the extended slice notation in that it gives you an index with which you can then reach into the original array, instead of getting a "filtered" array. So they do have different use cases.

Comment: The biggest advantage of this answer is that it's much more readable than "extended slice notation", especially by non-python devs.

Answer (score 11):

```
items = range(10)
print items
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print items[1::2] # every other item after the second; slight variation
>>> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
]
```

Comment: The only answer to solve the sister problem: every-other-element has two interpretations.

Comment: @jdi Instead of `[1::2]`; What if I want every "other element" starting from `index = 0`? So `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]`. Thanks.

Comment: @StressedBoi_69420 the syntax is `[start:end:step]` so just change it to `[0::2]` to have it start at 0 instead of 1

Answer (score 8):

> *There are more ways than one to skin a cat.* - Seba Smith

```
arr = list(range(10)) # Range from 0-9

# List comprehension: Range with conditional
print [arr[index] for index in range(len(arr)) if index % 2 == 0]

# List comprehension: Range with step
print [arr[index] for index in range(0, len(arr), 2)]

# List comprehension: Enumerate with conditional
print [item for index, item in enumerate(arr) if index % 2 == 0]

# List filter: Index in range
print filter(lambda index: index % 2 == 0, range(len(arr)))

# Extended slice
print arr[::2]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
b = a[::2]
```

This uses the [extended slice syntax](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html).

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it like this!

```
    def skip_elements(elements):
        # Initialize variables
        new_list = []
        i = 0

        # Iterate through the list
        for words in elements:

            # Does this element belong in the resulting list?
            if i <= len(elements):
                # Add this element to the resulting list
                new_list.append(elements[i])
            # Increment i
                i += 2

        return new_list

    print(skip_elements(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"])) # Should be ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']
    print(skip_elements(['Orange', 'Pineapple', 'Strawberry', 'Kiwi', 'Peach'])) # Should be ['Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Peach']
    print(skip_elements([])) # Should be []
```

Comment: Please provide some description for your code, for further detail

Comment: I ran into this problem in coursera's "Crash course on python"; I don't like the hints(comments) offered by the course, like other answer mentioned, we could iterate using "2" as step in range() to skip elements, I don't understand why they ask to implement with nested loops and variable "words" are not used here.

Answer (score 1):

```
def skip_elements(elements):
   new_list = [ ]
   i = 0
   for element in elements:
       if i%2==0:
         c=elements[i]
         new_list.append(c)
       i+=1
  return new_list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Initialize variables
new_list = []
i = 0
# Iterate through the list
for i in range(len(elements)):
    # Does this element belong in the resulting list?
    if i%2==0:
        # Add this element to the resulting list
        new_list.append(elements[i])
    # Increment i
    i +=2

return new_list
```

Comment: please explain your code to improve your answer

Answer (score 0):

Using the for-loop like you have, one way is this:

```
def altElement(a):
    b = []
    j = False
    for i in a:
        j = not j
        if j:
            b.append(i)

    print b
```

j just keeps switching between 0 and 1 to keep track of when to append an element to b.

Comment: Why aren't you simply using a boolean as the toggle? Also, this is unspeakably unidiomatic.

Comment: I wrote it this way to mirror the author's attempt.  Yes, it's not very python like.  Sure, I'll happily edit and make it a bool...

Comment: this is a really poor approach considering you can use list slices

Comment: @bchurchill - I dont think the idea was to mirror exactly what the author was attempting. He stated he wasnt even sure the right way to do it at all. It would be a lot better to point him towards the idiomatic way of doing it in python

Answer (score 0):

```
def skip_elements(elements):
  new_list = []
  for index,element in enumerate(elements):
    if index == 0:
      new_list.append(element)
    elif (index % 2) == 0: 
      new_list.append(element)
  return new_list
```

Also can use for loop + enumerate. 
        elif (index % 2) == 0: ## Checking if number is even, not odd cause indexing starts from zero not 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    # Initialize variables
    i = 0
    new_list=elements[::2]
    return new_list

# Should be ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']:    
print(skip_elements(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]))
# Should be ['Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Peach']:
print(skip_elements(['Orange', 'Pineapple', 'Strawberry', 'Kiwi', 'Peach'])) 
# Should be []:
print(skip_elements([]))
```

Comment: Here is your output:
['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']
['Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Peach']
[]

Answer (score 0):

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    # Initialize variables
    new_list = []
    i = 0

    # Iterate through the list
    for words in elements:
        # Does this element belong in the resulting list?
        if i <= len(elements):
            # Add this element to the resulting list
            new_list.insert(i,elements[i])
        # Increment i
        i += 2

    return new_list
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    # code goes here
    new_list=[]
    for index,alpha in enumerate(elements):
        if index%2==0:
            new_list.append(alpha)
    return new_list


print(skip_elements(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]))  
print(skip_elements(['Orange', 'Pineapple', 'Strawberry', 'Kiwi', 'Peach']))
```

Comment: TE A 24, I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please add an explanation of how this works and why it is suppoed to help.

Comment: Ok........I first create new list ....In the for loop we enumerate because we have to play with the index number that means odd or even...then if condition apply ....if  index is divisible by 2 then we have to append or add it......

Answer (score -2):

```
def skip_elements(elements):
# Initialize variables
new_list = []
i = 0

# Iterate through the list
for i in range(0,len(elements),2):
    # Does this element belong in the resulting list?
    if len(elements) > 0:
        # Add this element to the resulting list
        new_list.append(elements[i])        
return new_list

print(skip_elements(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"])) # Should be ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']
print(skip_elements(['Orange', 'Pineapple', 'Strawberry', 'Kiwi', 'Peach'])) # Should be ['Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Peach']
print(skip_elements([])) # Should be []
```