# Odd numbers using enumerator

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate over a list using enumerator in Python, but I want to display only those element that are at odd index of the list. Please note that I do not wish to use the standard step of dividing and checking remainder by 2

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `for i, item in enumerate(list_name[1::2]):...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping every other element after the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865878/skipping-every-other-element-after-the-first)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = range(1,10)
for x, y in enumerate(a):
     if not (x % 2):
         print(y)
```

edit: downvotes? that's not very nice, y'all

Comment: "I do not wish to use the standard step of dividing and checking remainder by 2"

Comment: he could keep an idx if he wanted and even/odd it, but whatever, i'm pretty sure with the question level, having modulo do the work for him is acceptable

Comment: @keen can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, item in enumerate(list_name[1::2]):...
```