# How to use a for loop to print every other item in a list?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list named "ul_children", I need to use a for loop to print every other item in that list starting with the second item or the index[1]. I am new to for loops in python and I am struggling with this.

I have tried a few different things I thought would work, but I have been unsuccessful so far. Any help would be appreciated.

The closest I have gotten so far is by using:

```
i = 1
for li in ul_children: 
   print(ul_children[i])
```

but I don't know how to get 'i' to increase each time the loop is performed.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far. You should have a look at the built-in function [`range()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp).

Comment: `for child in ul_children[1::2]`: print(child)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865878/skipping-every-other-element-after-the-first

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
ul_children = ["r","a","t","o","n"]

for i in ul_children[1:]:

    print(i)
```